# Getting the first digit of an int

Tags: sorting, go, indexing, int

How do I sort a slice of ints by the first digit of each int?

I am trying to write my own custom sort:

```
type ByFirstDigit []int

func (s ByFirstDigit) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func (s ByFirstDigit) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func (s ByFirstDigit) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i][0] < s[j][0]
}
```

But I get this error:

> s[j][0] (type int does not support indexing)

Comment: Can the numbers be negative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@RayfenWindspear has the easiest to use and read answer, but is correct about the performance hit. If performance is more important than maintainability, you can do the same thing using iterative division to get the most-significant base-10 digit:

```
var i int
for i = n; i >= 10; i = i / 10 {}
// i == most significant digit
```

Note that you have to declare `i` outside the loop to be able to use it after the loop finds the most-significant digit. I'd also benchmark both with your own data set to see what the real performance impact is in your particular situation.

[Full playground example, courtesy of Rayfen](https://play.golang.org/p/ozFw_ll6Y3).

Comment: Awesome! Not sure why I didn't think of this. My first thought was bitwise operators, but obviously that wouldn't work, so I went straight for the easy answer.

Comment: I usually prefer the easy answer because it's more clear what's going on. Then when the implementation is done, if performance doesn't meet requirements, benchmark, profile, and optimize. Premature optimization is the root of all evil :)

Comment: BTW, this has a bug in it in the fact that it doesn't account for the number `10`. `10` should be the first value. See here https://play.golang.org/p/eYZMVXQURS

Comment: Feel free to just fix it in that playground and use it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert them to strings in your sort function then index the first character. For `[]int` you can use https://godoc.org/strconv#Itoa . Unfortunately this method will take a huge performance hit for the string conversion.

https://play.golang.org/p/S4j3NlfinD

```
type ByFirstDigit []int

func (s ByFirstDigit) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func (s ByFirstDigit) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func (s ByFirstDigit) Less(i, j int) bool {
    si := strconv.Itoa(s[i])
    sj := strconv.Itoa(s[j])
    return si[0] < sj[0]
}
```

Comment: The `strconv` package has the `Append*` functions for formatting without the extra string conversion.

Comment: @JimB but the result would be a `[]byte`, which would have to be cast to `string` to use anyway. I'm at a loss as to how `Append*` functions would be better.

Comment: no, you don't need to format it as a string to get the first digit, the first `byte` in the slice is the first digit. It's faster, because it doesn't need to allocate the new string every time (internally FormatInt formats into a `[]byte` first the just calls `string(s)`), and you can reuse the buffer if you're really trying save. However it will still be slower than the direct solution of finding _only_ the first digit like in Adrian's solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a solution with a lot of high-level math functions that may or may not perform well:

```
package main

import "sort"
import "fmt"
import "math"

type ByFirstDigit []int

func (s ByFirstDigit) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s ByFirstDigit) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
func (s ByFirstDigit) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return firstDigit( s[i] ) < firstDigit( s[j] )
}

func firstDigit( x int ) int {
    return int( math.Abs( float64( x ) ) / math.Pow( 10, float64( numDigits(x) - 1 ) ) )
}

func numDigits( x int ) int {
    if ( x == 0 ) { return 1 }
    return int( math.Floor( math.Log10( math.Abs( float64(x) ) ) ) ) + 1
}

func main() {
    ints := []int{3, 20, 400, -500, 101}
    sort.Sort( ByFirstDigit( ints ) )
    fmt.Println( ints )
}
```

Here's a playground (same code):
https://play.golang.org/p/uLyBMlra2N

Comment: I always forget, is the precision of a `float64` such that it is capable of holding __any whole number__ within the `int64` range without some truncating happening? i.e. is there the possibility of `int64(float64(n)) != n` where `n` is originally `int64`?

Comment: No, are ints in Go 64 bits? (I haven't used Go before). Range of an int64: 2^64. Perfect int range of a float64: 2^53, because you get 52 perfect bits from the mantissa, and one from the exponent.

Comment: The `int` type is based off system architecture, but is still it's own type. On x64 it will be `int64` but doesn't mean that the types `int` and `int64` are the same, a cast is necessary.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what the downvote was for - anything specific in the code I can fix? I'm new to Go, so always looking for tips.

Comment: @jbjw: The issue here is that `int` in Go can (and most often is) 64bits, so so converting values greater than `1<<52` to float64 can lose precision. Take the number `999999999999999999` for example: https://play.golang.org/p/ECNnjhJ-CR -- RayfenWindspear hinted at the bug, but someone should probably have pointed it out directly rather than down-voting.